# Reactjs simple render problem , how can i manipulate json object into render()

Tags: reactjs

I am very new on React, and I have some troubles to understand how to fix my problem:

I have the following object which I would like to render using react

```
const festivals = [
  {
    festivalName: "festival XXX",
    setting: [
      { deviceID: "001", qty: "100" },
      { deviceID: "002", qty: "700" }
    ]
  },
  {
    festivalName: "festival YYY",
    setting: [
      { deviceID: "003", qty: "666" },
      { deviceID: "004", qty: "400" },
      { deviceID: "005", qty: "555" }
    ]
  }
];
```

the expected rendering is the following:

> - XXX
>
>   - deviceID : 001, qty : 100
>   - deviceID : 002, qty : 700
> - YYY
>
>   - deviceID : 003, qty : 666
>   - deviceID : 004, qty : 400
>   - deviceID : 005, qty : 555

here is the code:

```
import React from "react";


function ListItemFest(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <li>{props.value}</li>
    </div>
  );
}

function ListItemFestData(props) {
  var data = JSON.parse(props.value);
  var rendertext = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    rendertext = rendertext + data[i].deviceID + ":" + data[i].qty;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>{rendertext}</ul>{" "}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function FestivalsList(props) {
  const f = props.festivals;
  const listItems = f.map(festival => (
    <div>
      <ListItemFest key={festival.festivalName} value={festival.festivalName} />
      <ListItemFestData
        key={festival.festivalName}
        value={JSON.stringify(festival.cuves)}
      />
    </div>
  ));
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}

const festivals = [
  {
    festivalName: "XXX",
    cuves: [{ deviceID: "001", qty: "100" }, { deviceID: "002", qty: "700" }]
  },
  {
    festivalName: "YYY",
    cuves: [
      { deviceID: "003", qty: "666" },
      { deviceID: "004", qty: "400" },
      { deviceID: "005", qty: "555" }
    ]
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FestivalsList festivals={festivals} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

> the rendering is the following:
>
> XXX 001:100002:700 YYY 003:666004:400005:555
>
> for each 'festival', deviceID and qty are displayed in one unique row
>
> How can I do to have the following ?
>
> - XXX
>
>   - deviceID : 001, qty : 100
>   - deviceID : 002, qty : 700
> - YYY
>
>   - deviceID : 003, qty : 666
>   - deviceID : 004, qty : 400
>   - deviceID : 005, qty : 555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is more an HTML problem than a react one, and the lines that are causing the issue are the ones with the for:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  rendertext = rendertext + data[i].deviceID + ":" + data[i].qty;
}
```

on those lines you are concatenating everything in one line, when you need a list, I cleaned up the code a bit and proposed a solution below, my recommendation is to learn a bit more javascript and HTML before diving onto react, hope this helps!

```
import React from "react";

function ListItemFest(props) {
  return (
      <div>{props.value}</div>
  );
}

function ListItemFestData(props) {
  return (
      <ul>
        {props.value.map((data)=> {
          return <li key={data.deviceID}>{`deviceID: ${data.deviceID}, qty: ${data.qty}`}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
  );
}

function FestivalsList(props) {
  const f = props.festivals;
  const listItems = f.map(festival => (
    <li>
      <ListItemFest key={festival.festivalName} value={festival.festivalName} />
      <ListItemFestData
        key={festival.festivalName + 'data'}
        value={festival.cuves}
      />
    </li>
  ));
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}

const festivals = [
  {
    festivalName: "XXX",
    cuves: [{ deviceID: "001", qty: "100" }, { deviceID: "002", qty: "700" }]
  },
  {
    festivalName: "YYY",
    cuves: [
      { deviceID: "003", qty: "666" },
      { deviceID: "004", qty: "400" },
      { deviceID: "005", qty: "555" }
    ]
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FestivalsList festivals={festivals} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

read more about HTML lists here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 0):

```
festivals.map((item,index)=>{
    <>
    {item.festivalName}
    item.setting.map((ele,key)=>{
        {ele.deviceId}
        {ele.qty}
    })
    </>
})
```

try this i think this'll work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution here ..

```
/* festivals array*/
const festivals = [
  {
    festivalName: "festival XXX",
    setting: [
      { deviceID: "001", qty: "100" },
      { deviceID: "002", qty: "700" }
    ]
  },
  {
    festivalName: "festival YYY",
    setting: [
      { deviceID: "003", qty: "666" },
      { deviceID: "004", qty: "400" },
      { deviceID: "005", qty: "555" }
    ]
  }
];
/* React class that would be rendered as HTML*/
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul>
          {
            /*apply map method to the festivals array */
            festivals.map( (item, idx) => {
              return(
                <li key={idx}>{item.festivalName.substring(item.festivalName.length-3)}
                  <ul>
                  {
                    item.setting.map( (el, idx) => {
                      return(
                        <li key={idx}>
                          deviceID:{el.deviceID}, qty:{el.qty}
                        </li>
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </ul>
                </li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

You may further improve it from there.
        [codenpen](https://codepen.io/pterala/pen/abvyZGx)